# Retrieve data from multiple table in sql using some condition

Tags: mysql

I have created three tables namely

studentdetails (sid,sname,slname),
books (bid,bname,bprice),
bookingdetails (sid,bid)

[sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6QzT.png)

I want to display the student name who has booked dbms book.

Answer (score 1):

JOINS should do the work, like the query below:

```
SELECT studentdetails.name from books 
inner join bookingdetails on bookingdetails.bid = books.bid
inner join studentdetails on studentdetails.id = bookingdetails.sid
where books.name = 'dbms'
```

Answer (score 0):

Join help us to fetch data from multiple table,so below query can work :

```
 SELECT Slname 
   FROM studentdetails sd 
   JOIN BookingDetails bd 
     ON sd.sid = bd.sid 
   JOIN books bk  
     ON bk.bid = bd.bid 
    AND bk.bname = 'DBMS'
```

Comment: nothing seems to change in the query i am written earlier. You are replaced inner join with join. By default join work as inner join , then what the concern of editing this?